# How to get the arc to touch the x-axis using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

One more time, there is a figure I don't seem to get right. This is the desired output:

[image]

This is what I get so far:

[image]

And this is a MWE that generates what I get:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0pt, every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={stealth-}}, every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black}, dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}}, line/.style = {-stealth, shorten >=1mm, shorten <= 1mm},]
\coordinate (s) at (3,3);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-0.5,0.5);
\coordinate[right=55mm of O] (X);
\coordinate[above=55mm of O] (Y);
\coordinate[above right=1 and 2 of O] (d);
\coordinate[right=2 of X |- Y] (e);
\coordinate (a) at (10,10);
\draw[-latex] ([xshift=-0.1] O) -- (X) node[right] {$h_1$};
\draw[-latex] ([yshift=-0.1] O) -- (Y) node[above] {$h_2$};
\path[name path=S] (O) -- (45:6);
\coordinate[left =of s -| O] (s1);
\coordinate[below=of s |- O] (s2);
\draw[Blue,thick] let \p1 = ($(s)-(O)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ($(O)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:90:\n1);
\draw[Blue,thick] let \p1 = ($(s)-(P)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:83.5:\n1);
\node[dot,at=(s),pin=60:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
\node[below] at (1,1) {$d$};
\node[below] at (1,4) {$S$};
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle (2pt);
\path[name path=D] (s2) -- (15:8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could anyone please help me get the desired output? I am afraid I am missing something rather stupid, but I don't know what it is. Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: As with your last question, `dvipsnames` is required for the example to work, to define the color `Blue`. But the example doesn't work anyway, I get `no shape named s is known`, can fix that? And add `\end{document}` as well, while you're at it.

Comment: What a bad MWE. I'm sorry. I am editing my question now.

Comment: No worries, just remember to always test the code before you post it.

Comment: It may take longer than I thought. When I compile the figure in its original tex file, I get the posted output. When I run the MWE, I get something different. I need to check what's happening because I don't get it.

Comment: You just need to add `[dvipsnames]` as a class option, add the `document` environment, and finally define the `s` coordinate properly. Adding something like `\coordinate (s) at (3,3);` near the start, and it works fine.

Comment: Took me a while, but it should compile now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated my answer with a way of calculating the angles, so you don't have to find the ~83.5 degrees manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start the `arc` 0.5 above the x-axis, because its starting point is `(P)+(\n1,0)`, and `P` is at (-0.5,0.5). You can draw the curve counterclockwise from that point in addition, to extend it down to the axis, i.e.

```
\draw[Blue,thick] let
  \p1 = ($(s)-(P)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
  ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:83.4:\n1)
  ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:-6.6:\n1);
```

But a perhaps easier way of doing the same is to clip two circles, with the help of the `through` library, i.e.

```
\begin{scope}
\clip (X) rectangle (Y);
\node [draw,thick,circle,Blue,circle through=(s)] at (O) {};
\node [draw,thick,circle,Blue,circle through=(s)] at (P) {};
\end{scope}
```

Complete code, where I removed some unused elements, and tidied up a bit:

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, arrows.meta, through}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0pt,
  every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={Stealth-}},
  every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black},
  dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}},
]
\coordinate (s) at (3,3);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-0.5,0.5);
\coordinate[right=55mm of O] (X);
\coordinate[above=55mm of O] (Y);

\draw[Latex-Latex] (Y) node[above] {$h_2$} -- (O) -- (X) node[right] {$h_1$};

%alternative 1
%\begin{scope}
%\clip (X) rectangle (Y);
%\node [draw,thick,circle,Blue,circle through=(s)] at (O) {};
%\node [draw,thick,circle,Blue,circle through=(s)] at (P) {};
%\end{scope}

% alternative 2
\draw[Blue,thick] let
  \p1 = ($(s)-(O)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
 ($(O)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:90:\n1);
\draw[Blue,thick] let
  \p1 = ($(s)-(P)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
  ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:83.4:\n1)
  ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:-6.6:\n1);
% end alternative 2
%%%%%%%


\node[dot,at=(s),pin=60:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
\node[dot,at={(1,1)},label=below:{$d$}];
\node[below] at (1,4) {$S$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Calculate angles

To avoid finding the angles in your code by trial and error, you can calculate them, see example below.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, arrows.meta, through,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0pt,
  every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={Stealth-}},
  every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black},
  dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}},
]
\coordinate (s) at (3,3);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-0.5,0.5);
\coordinate[right=55mm of O] (X);
\coordinate[above=55mm of O] (Y);

% note name path=axis
\draw[Latex-Latex,name path=axis] (Y) node[above] {$h_2$} -- (O) -- (X) node[right] {$h_1$};

\draw[Blue,thick] let
  \p1 = ($(s)-(O)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
 ($(O)+(\n1,0)$) arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\n1];


% define circle around P through s
\path[overlay,name path=circle] let
  \p1 = ($(s)-(P)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
(P) circle[radius=\n1];
% calculate angles between P and intersection points with circle and axis lines
\draw[Red,thick,name intersections={of=axis and circle,name=i}] let
  \p1 = ($(i-1)-(P)$),
  \p2 = ($(i-2)-(P)$),
  \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
  \n2 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)},
  \n3 = {atan2(\y2,\x2)}
in
  (i-1) arc[radius=\n1,start angle=\n2,end angle=\n3];


\node[dot,at=(s),pin=60:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
\node[dot,at={(1,1)},label=below:{$d$}];
\node[below] at (1,4) {$S$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

So as not to bother with computations, draw a full circle, and `clip` the part we are interested in (upper right quadrant).

[image]

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0pt, every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={stealth-}}, every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black}, dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}}, line/.style = {-stealth, shorten >=1mm, shorten <= 1mm},]
  \coordinate (s) at (3,3);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (P) at (-0.5,0.5);
  \coordinate[right=55mm of O] (X);
  \coordinate[above=55mm of O] (Y);
  \coordinate[above right=1 and 2 of O] (d);
  \coordinate[right=2 of X |- Y] (e);
  \coordinate (a) at (10,10);
  \draw[-latex] ([xshift=-0.1] O) -- (X) node[right] {$h_1$};
  \draw[-latex] ([yshift=-0.1] O) -- (Y) node[above] {$h_2$};
  \path[name path=S] (O) -- (45:6);
  \coordinate[left =of s -| O] (s1);
  \coordinate[below=of s |- O] (s2);
  \draw[Blue,thick] let \p1 = ($(s)-(O)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ($(O)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:90:\n1);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (X) rectangle (Y);
    \draw[Blue,thick] let \p1 = ($(s)-(P)$), \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ($(P)+(\n1,0)$) arc(0:360:\n1);
  \end{scope}
  \node[dot,at=(s),pin=60:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
  \node[below] at (1,1) {$d$};
  \node[below] at (1,4) {$S$};
  \draw[fill] (1,1) circle (2pt);
  \path[name path=D] (s2) -- (15:8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more possible solution (bases on experiences of your previous similar questions):

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, fit, intersections, 
                matrix, positioning, 
                through, patterns}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10mm and 20mm, 
 every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={stealth-}}, 
every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black}, 
       dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}},
      line/.style = {-stealth, shorten >=1mm, shorten <= 1mm}
                    ]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[above right=of O] (d);
% axis
\draw[-latex] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$h_1$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.1) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$h_2$};
% arc
\draw[Blue,thick,name path=A]       (4.0,0) arc(0:90:4);
\draw[TealBlue,thick,name path=B]   (4.5,0) arc(0:90:5 and 3.5);
% intersection, dashed S line
\draw[densely dashed, name intersections={of=A and B, by={s}}]
    (s -| O) -| ( s|- O) node[pos=0.25,above] {$S$};
\node[dot,at=(s), pin=above right:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
% d point
\node[dot,at=(d), label=below:$d$];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum:* in case that `S` and `T` are names of arcus thanthe following MWE show, how to do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvipsnames,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, fit, intersections, 
                matrix, positioning, 
                through, patterns}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10mm and 20mm, 
 every pin/.style = {pin distance=11mm, pin edge={stealth-}}, 
every node/.style = {color=Blue!60!black}, 
       dot/.style = {circle, fill=black, inner sep=0mm, minimum size=2mm, node contents={}},
      line/.style = {-stealth, shorten >=1mm, shorten <= 1mm}
                    ]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[above right=of O] (d);
% axis
\draw[-latex] (-0.1,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$h_1$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.1) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$h_2$};
% arc
\draw[Blue,thick,name path=A]       (4.0,0) arc(0:90:4) node[above right] {$S$};
\draw[TealBlue,thick,name path=B]   (4.5,0) arc(0:90:4.5 and 3.5) node[above right] {$T$};
% intersection, dashed S line
\coordinate[densely dashed, name intersections={of=A and B, by={s}}];
\node[dot,at=(s), pin=75:{$f(T,d)=f(S,d)$}];
% d point
\node[dot,at=(d), label=below:$d$];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]